# Win Server2003 /Classic ASP: Connect PDA SDF with SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-ce, ado

I want to connect an SDF database taken from PDA with SQL Compact Edition 4.0 and Classic ASP.

I own a small server with Windows Server 2003.

These are the steps that I have done:

1. Putting the SDF file inside a folder in my IIS website (i.e.: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\db\`)
2. Download and install SQL Server Compact 4.0 from Microsoft
3. `regserv32` to the `sqlceca40.dll` and `sqlceoledb40.dll` files
4. After this I made security setting on each folder setting to `IURS_` the rights
5. Now I made a Classic ASP file with this:

   ```
   strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\db\PdaDatabase.sdf;ssce:database Password=mypassword;"
   set my_Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set my_Comm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   my_Conn.Open strConnString
   my_Comm.ActiveConnection = my_Conn
   ```

Once I did start the script (from another computer in the LAN), this is the results:

> error '80004005'
>
> /MyTestASP.asp, line 4

Any suggestion?

Comment: No PDAs support SQL Server Compact 4, only 3,5.

Comment: I was following your blog and after this post I realized that the real problem was the SDF version. Now I will try to use the 3.5. Thank you very much. Oscar

Comment: I tried but nothing. Still the same error. I installed the version 3.5, regsrv32 on the two dll, everything ok but when I create the database connection, ASP gives me the same error code. Now I used the string:"Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\db\PdaDatabase.sdf;ssce:database Password=mypassword;". Any suggestion? Thanks. Oscar

Comment: Make sure that the web server process can write to the database folder

Comment: Yes. IIS_WPG and IURS_ can write. I think that is a file version issue. The CAB of PDA setup to install SQL CE has this filename "sqlce30.ppc.wce4.armv4.CAB" so I think that file version is 3.0/3.1 but I can't view this. If I upgrade SDF to 4.0 with SDF Viewer app, the error disappears (with SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0). But I can't convert the SDF 'cause the file version must be the same of the PDA SQL. So I'm lookng for an ASP ADODB solution (as SQL COMPACT 3.5/4.0) to Open the native database (without conversion), apply some query like UPDATE/INSERT and put the modified file in PDA.

Comment: It sounds like "I want to use this string Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.1" but I can find an ADODB dll to use with Classic ASP

Comment: Ok. Now I have the database version. It is 3.0.5300.0

Comment: OK, thanks, maybe you should update your question, then. The OLEDB provider name is: Microsoft.SQLSERVER.MOBILE.OLEDB.3.0 and the runtime is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17439

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41491/discussion-between-oscar-zarrus-and-erikej)